# Can't install Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 24.2.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Hello I tried to update Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 but I get this error (( Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.3.1 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.3.1)'.))
  => the target android version : android 7.0 API 24

Comment: Are you using the new template with .net standard 2.0 ?

Comment: is just cross platform project

Comment: Go to the project properties in your Forms project (not android or ios) and you can notice which one is.

Comment: .net framework 4.5

Comment: asp.net core 1.0